# Optimizing a table's index in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, query-optimization, database-indexes

I have the following table (tracking searches):

```sql
CREATE TABLE `searches` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `deleted` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `query` varchar(1024) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `userId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `connectionId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `pluginId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `key,deleted` (`publicId`,`deleted`),
  KEY `deleted,userId` (`deleted`,`userId`),
  KEY `deleted,connectionId,pluginId` (`deleted`,`connectionId`,`pluginId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Sometimes, I run queries to return all the queries done by a specific user. In that case, I have an index with the following columns: `deleted`,`userId`

Other times, I run queries to return all the queries done by specific "connection" and "plugin". In that case, I have an index with the following columns: `deleted`,`connectionId`,`pluginId`

The size of the indexes are growing substantially, and so I'm trying to understand how I could better optimize these.

Would there be value in combine both indexes into one? For example, it would have the following columns: `deleted`,`userId`,`connectionId`,`pluginId`

I'm not sure if this would result in a smaller index while fulfilling the queries in a acceptable with.

Comment: Why is `deleted` the leading column? It's by far, presumably, the least selective.

Comment: Since every query I write includes a condition for only deleted records, shouldn't it be part of the index?

Comment: Probably not but it depends, and probably not the leading column unless it can have many values for different types of deletedness....

Comment: If about every query includes a condition on the `deleted` column, you may consider partitioning the table. Thus you would always either select in the deleted or undeleted part of the data and wouldn't have to include this in any index. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning.html

Comment: As to the indexes. Don't combine them, as this would make the index less usable or even unusable for one of the queries.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @ThorstenKettner I'll look into the partitioning approach down the line; at the moment, my focus is on lowering the size of the index while trying to maintain it's value (without too many changes to the underlying data structure).

Comment: @Stu thanks. I didn't know that the order of the columns has an effect. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an INDEX multiple times, but only from left to right without missing a field.
Example:
Index (fieldA,fieldB,fieldC)
then you can use this for fieldA or fieldA and fieldB or fieldA,fieldB, fieldC but not for an access to fieldA and fieldC or fieldB and fieldC.

So this doesn't work for your queries

Comment: Thanks @bernd-buffen as mentioned above, I didn't know the order (left to right) of the columns in the index had such an effect. I'll look more into this.